# Data processing from uart

Tags: java, uart

I'm stuck upon this problem writing code for an application in Java, that is connected with external device Uc which takes samples from multiple channels of ADC and sends them back to app for proccessing and graphing. My problem is, that I don't know how to sort and store data of samples corresponing to each sampled channel for later processing, since I can not graph all data coming let's say from 3 different channels at once. Any suggestions would greatly appreciated!

Comment: that uC sends measured ADC samples via serial port and you don't know "which data comes from which channel". is that correct?

Comment: No, i know which channel data comes from , because i assigned diffrent ID to diffrent channel, but i'm having problems with graphing received samples. I could do it with singal channel, but when you have more than one channel you need to extract all samples and store for every channel and then graph one sample at a time, then increase time veriable of graph so graph moves a long, like in real-time graphing monitoring sort of system. This is the part i can't seem to find the solution for. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a global int variable(say int eventTimer) and create a timer that'll have its own thread which increases this eventTimer on each timer tick. Set the timer's period according to sampling rate.

2) create a map for each channel to store "reading time and read value" like:

```
Map<int, float> readingsFromChannel1 = new HashMap<int, float>();
```

and whenever you receive a new reading from that channel, append it into its map like:

```
float value; // the value that you just get from channel 1
readingsFromChannel1.put(eventTimer, value);
```

3) in your drawing function of the graph:

```
// drawing of channel1 data:
iterator it = readingsFromChannel1.iterator();
while(it.next())
{
  Map.Entry m =(Map.Entry)it.next();
  int key=(Integer)m.getKey();
  float value=(float)m.getValue();
  // I assume that you have a putpixel(x,y) method for drawing:
  putPixel(key - eventTimer, value);
}
```

Comment: so this would work for mulitiple channels, say being graphed at same time, wouldn't it? And if it would than how would you iterate through diffrent maps of channels at same time if their size varied.

Comment: yes, it should work with multiple channels. since you call it.next() in the loop, you don't need to know the size.

Comment: if it works, can you mark my answer as "correct answer" please?

Comment: Ok will do. I didn't get to test this method yet, because i'm waiting on a new microcontroller with development board, since i accidently blew up and destroy my old one. Can i ask you one more question? Do you think this work if i take number of samples of each channel, say take 20 samples from channel 1, and send them to computer, after take same nuber of samples from diffrent channel. I'm just wondering how your method would work with timerInterval counter, since channel samples coming in at 20 samples at time..